# iOS SVG sprite img tag not showing

Tags: html, css, svg, sprite, mobile-safari

I made a stacked svg sprite and I want to show the svg's in a img tag and I want to use it in my css files.

I'm embedding the images like this:

```
<img src="http://markputs.nl/sprite/sitesprite.svg#audio">
```

and http://markputs.nl/sprite/sitesprite.svg is the svg.

(sorry that I need to link to the svg but I think it might be important to have the entire file)

I found some old topics at this site where the issue could be resolved by serving the svg as an actual svg but I'm already serving it as an actual svg (file type).

I have no idea how to fix this, is there someone that can help me in the right direction? It's working on all major browsers except ios browsers..

Comment: did you inspect the file?? your svg root display is set to none

Comment: Check this [image](https://ibb.co/bTTDEd)

Comment: @Adam I needed to use :root>svg{display:none}:root>svg:target{display:block} css because otherwise all icons are shown at once. It looks like the :target css isn't working, but I have no idea how to work around this..